# NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, three.js

I'm debugging threejs javascript code in Chrome.

I have the following:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/goal.js", function(geo) {
//blah blah
});
```

I have a folder 'models' with the file goal.js inside it.

In the below function I get the following error on the f.send()

**uncaught error NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101**

```
THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.loadAjaxJSON=function(a,b,c,d,e)
{
    var f=new XMLHttpRequest,g=0;
    f.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(4==f.readyState)if(200==f.status||0==f.status)
        {
            try
            {
                var h=JSON.parse(f.responseText)
            }
            catch(i)
            {
                console.warn("DEPRECATED: ["+b+"] seems to be using old model format")
            }
            a.createModel(h,c,d);
            a.onLoadComplete()
        }
        else
        console.error("Couldn't load ["+b+"] ["+f.status+"]");

        else 3==f.readyState?e&&(0==g&&(g=f.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")),e({total:g,loaded:f.responseText.length})):2==f.readyState&&(g=f.getResponseHeader("Content-Length"))
    };

    f.open("GET",b,!0);
    f.overrideMimeType&&f.overrideMimeType("text/plain; charset=x-user-defined");
    f.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
    **f.send(null)**
};
```

ANy ideas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965942/network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101

Comment: Tip: do not debug with a minified version of THREE.js. (use `three.js` instead of `three.min.js`) -- and make sure you are using the current version, r.56.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the security policy in Chrome for accessing local files.

Start a Chrome executable with a command line flag:

```
chrome --allow-file-access-from-files
```

On Windows, you can create a shortcut which has the added flag. (right-click on shortcut -> properties -> target)

See the [Wiki article](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have did this and I'm still getting the same error :(