# Safari browser ajax request error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cross-domain

I'm making ajax request to the  generic handler `Handler.ashx`, which forwards this request to a REST service in another domain. Handler is used to achieve cross-domain call.
I get the data in Firefox & Chrome. But not in Safari on Windows 7(Ver. 5.1.7)

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'Handler.ashx',
         type: 'GET',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         async: false,
         timeout: 20000,
         data: data,
         success: function (received_data) {
             // Process data
         },
         error: function (err) {
             console.log(err);
         }
});
```

My `Handler.ashx` code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/MyWebService/Service.svc/DownloadFile"));
    req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    req.Timeout = 60000;

    using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse()) 
    { 
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string responceFromService = reader.ReadToEnd();
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        context.Response.Write(responceFromService);
    }
```

The error I get is:

`NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965942/network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15913170/phantom-js-synchronous-ajax-request-network-err-xmlhttprequest-exception-101

Comment: I am also getting the same error like "Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101", I have also seen above links still not get any solution can anyone tell me what exactly problem with the safari browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From everything I can find surfing around on the web, and my own testing, Safari times out synchronous ajax calls after 10 seconds. And, there is no way to get around it. (I've tried.) This is not a bug. It is simply Apple's way of hinting to you that if your call can't reliably return in 10 seconds, you shouldn't be using a synchronous call. In fact, you probably shouldn't ever use a synchronous call because there is no way to know if your call will return in 10 seconds. You need to refactor your code to have whatever would happen after the ajax call, happen via the callback routine, and not in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `async` parameter to `true`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Handler.ashx',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I can not go further until I get the data & process it. I'm building blocks with the help of that data.

Comment: So just code your logic by calling relevant functions inside the complete callback function, there is no valable reason to use ajax async false, none im aware of.

Comment: @A. Wolff: I am also having the same problem, my ajax call is working in all browsers except safari. can you please explain me what exactly fault it.

Answer (score 0):

My ajax call were failing only in Safari. What worked for me was preventing the default button click behavior using `event.preventDefault()`